# Characteristic polynomial (to see which directional blow-ups have to be made)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, blowup

For some positive $a\in\mathbb{R}$ let
$$
\dot{x}=ax^2-2xy,\quad \dot{y}=y^2-axy
$$
$(0,0)$ is a degenerate equilibrium and thus directional blow-ups are made.

It is said [here, p. 4 below](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50803305_A_survey_on_the_blow_up_technique):

> [...] we use the directional blow ups to desingularize the origin [...] the characteristic polynomial of this system is $\mathcal{F}(x,y)=xy(3y-2ax)$. Therefore we need to do both directional blow ups to get the complete local phase portrait around the origin, as $x=0$ and $y=0$ are both characteristic directions. [...]

A stupid question, but: How to get this characteristic polynomial $\mathcal{F}(x,y)=xy(3y-2ax)$? I do not understand what is meant with "characteristic polynomial" in this cited paper. There are other examples given for which I also do not see how they get what they call "characteristic polynomial".

---

If I do, for example, the blow-up in the x-direction, $(x,z)\mapsto (x,xz)=(x,y)$, I get the system
$$
\dot{x}=ax^2-2x^2z,\qquad \dot{z}=3xz^2-2axz=xz(3z-2a).
$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the equation for $(\dot x,\dot y)\sim(x,y)$, that is, points where the vector field is radial. Then the equation is 
$$
0=\det\pmatrix{x&y\\\dot x&\dot y}=xg(x,y)-yf(x,y)=xy((y-ax)-(ax-2y))=xy(3y-2ax).
$$

Comment: Does this fit in general? Another example given in the paper is $\dot{x}=y, \dot{y}=x^2+xy$. And they claim the characteristic polynomial is $\mathcal{F}=y^2$. Again, I do not see how they get there.

Comment: It still fits the pattern, if you only consider the terms of the lowest degree in the result, that is, those terms that would be dominant if you zoom in to zero. There is a sign difference, so perhaps there is still a different (but equivalent) formula.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am wondering why this characteristic polynomial is relevant for the directional blow-ups, i.e. what is the role of it. Unfortunately this is not explained in the paper (maybe it’s obvious for others...).